# Moving backwards in a singly linked list?

Tags: java

I'm creating my first linked list and while I understand doubly linked lists are really for going backwards I am attempting to create a method that moves the current node backwards in the list by one node in a SINGLY linked list.

Here's what I got so far, I've included my go to next for reference and constructors:

```
  //Paramaterized construct
  public ListNode(int aData, ListNode aLink) {
    this.data= aData;
    this.link = aLink;
  }
}
private ListNode head; //First element
private ListNode current; //Current node of interest
private ListNode previous; //Node behind current

public void goToNext () {
  previous = current;
  current = current.link;
}
//TODO: Fix previous
public void goToPrev () {
  if (current != head) {
  }
  else 
    System.out.println("Current node is the head, sorry");
```

I forgot to add my private ListNode class:

```
private class ListNode
{
    private int data;
    private ListNode link;
    //Default construct
    public ListNode ()
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
    }
    //Paramaterized construct
    public ListNode(int aData, ListNode aLink)
    {
        this.data= aData;
        this.link = aLink;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I have to iterate from the start of the list until I find the node that has `next` equal to my current node. But I'm not sure how to exactly set up that while loop and have the correct body.

Comment: What is before `head`?

Comment: @DavidChoweller In my case, the 'follower' is previous & what would be the leader? Current? I'm a little unsure of what the follower would be here

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to iterate over the list with TWO pointers, not one. The trick is to have one ahead of the other by exactly one node, so when pointer #1 finds the node of interest, pointer #2 is the node behind it in the list and you can "move backwards" by accessing #2.

Comment: Or, you work with just one pointer `p` and check if `p.link == current`.

Comment: @Henry hmm one pointer sounds simpler than two, you got me curious

Comment: @ChrisM I don't want to give away the complete solution, but if the condition mentioned in my previous comment is true, which node is `p` pointing to?

Comment: @Henry Umm I suppose it would then be pointing to the head? I might be wrong though, this concept was introduced today and I am a bit confused

Comment: @ChrisM so you think `head.link == current` is always true? Not quite.

Comment: @Henry I apologize I am quite lost

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate singly linked list backwards. If you want to iterate backwards then you should you doubly linked list. Or you can achieve this take ref of the node before iterate.